# c# selenium How to click on a checkbox

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I would like to click a chechbox through C# and Selenium. The checkbox HTML is as follows :

```
<div class="ad-post-rules" ng-class="{'ad-post-rules-error': submitted &amp;&amp; addClassifiedForm.postRulesCheck.$error.required}" an-form-error="" an-form-error-optional-text="İlan verme kurallarını onaylamadınız."><input id="postRulesCheck" class="checkBox sg-checkbox ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" type="checkbox" value="1" name="postRulesCheck" ng-model="postRulesCheck" required="" an-form-object-name="İlan Verme Kuralları"><label for="postRulesCheck"></label><span class="rulesOpen" ng-click="adPostRules=true">İlan verme kurallarını</span><label for="postRulesCheck">okudum, kabul ediyorum</label></div>
```

My code is as follows :

```
Dim cekbul As IWebElement
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
cekbul = driver.FindElement(By.Id("#postRulesCheck"))
cekbul.Click()
```

Comment: Remove the '#' from the id. So say: driver.FindElement(By.Id("postRulesCheck"))

Comment: element not visible

Comment: use the javascript executor to click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To click on the checkbox as the element is an *Angular* element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the elelemt to be clickable and you can use either of the following option :

- `CssSelector` :

  ```
  var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
  wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("input.checkBox.sg-checkbox.ng-pristine.ng-untouched.ng-empty.ng-invalid.ng-invalid-required#postRulesCheck"))).Click();
  ```
- `XPath` :

  ```
  var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
  wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//input[@class='checkBox sg-checkbox ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required' and @id='postRulesCheck']"))).Click();
  ```

Comment: @HasanSarıkaya Checkout my updated answer as per your updated HTML and let me know the status.

Comment: Very thanx  dude   xpath selection is process.Every body very thanx

Answer (score 1):

I dont know coding in c sharp but i think it works

```
IWebElement Ele_CheckBox = driver.FindElement(By.Id("postRulesCheck"));

Ele_CheckBox.Click();
```

**By using name**

```
IWebElement Ele_CheckBox = driver.FindElement(By.Name("postRulesCheck"));

Ele_CheckBox.Click();
```

**By xpath**

```
IWebElement Ele_CheckBox = driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("//input[@id='postRulesCheck']"));

Ele_CheckBox.Click();
```

Comment: ckeck the visiblity using isdisplayed methiod

Answer (score 0):

Selenium can click only on element that is visible for a human. You can still execute javascript even if the element is not visible. If the element is visible for a human while you are trying to execute your test and still you are getting the element not visible exception , try to use Actions API instead otherwise use javascript.

```
 Actions action = new Actions(driver);
 IWebElement cekbul = driver.FindElement(By.Id("postRulesCheck"));
 action.Click(cekbul).Build().Perform();
```

This lets you click at a point irrespective of the location of point .